# How do you automatically detect device dimensions when using HTTP Live Streaming?

Tags: http-live-streaming

I have an app that delivers video content using HTTP Live Streaming. I want the app to retrieve the appropriate resolution based on the devices screen size (either 4x3 or 16x9). I ran Apple's tool to create the master .m3u8 playlist file (variantplaylistcreator) and got the following:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=248842,BANDWIDTH=394849,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d4028",RESOLUTION=480x360
4x3/lo/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=384278,BANDWIDTH=926092,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d4028",RESOLUTION=480x360
4x3/mid/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=787643,BANDWIDTH=985991,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.42801e",RESOLUTION=480x360
4x3/hi/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=249335,BANDWIDTH=392133,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d4028",RESOLUTION=640x360
16x9/lo/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=384399,BANDWIDTH=950686,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d4028",RESOLUTION=640x360
16x9/mid/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=780648,BANDWIDTH=987197,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.42801e",RESOLUTION=640x360
16x9/hi/prog_index.m3u8
```

This does cause my live stream to switch between video quality correctly, but it seems to randomly pick whether it uses a 4x3 or 16x9 resolution.

Is there a way to have it select the correct dimensions automatically, or do I need to have multiple playlist files and have a device request a specific one? For example, if on an iPad do I need to detect that it's screen has a 4x3 dimension and request a 4x3_playlist.m3u8 that only has the 480x360 resolution option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2017:**

Keeping the same aspect-ratio is only a recommendation in the latest [HLS authoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/HLSAuthoringSpec/Requirements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016596-CH2-SW1) guide:

> 1.33. All video variants **SHOULD** have identical aspect ratios.

**Original answer:**

---

> Audio/Video Stream Considerations:
>
> Video **aspect ratio must be exactly
>   the same**, but can be different dimensions.

[Apple Technical Note TN2224 - Best Practices for Creating and Deploying HTTP Live Streaming Media for the iPhone and iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html)

Select a playlist based on the **User-Agent** instead.